# Find particular file in a root directory in golang?

Tags: go

I have a below code which finds a particular file passed as an input parameter recursively in a root directory which contains sub directories too and then it returns the full path of that file.

```
func findFile(root string, fileName string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.WalkDir(root, func(path string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if !d.IsDir() && d.Name() == fileName {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}
```

This is how I use it -

```
findFile("/home", "abc.json")
```

It works fine but now I need to do one more thing. Instead of passing full complete fileName, I should also be able to pass something like this `prefix-*.json` which means find me all the files which starts with `prefix-` and ends with `.json` file type. Is there any way by which above method can be modified to work with both the cases? If not then what is the better way to do this?

I should be able to do below things and it will return me path of all those files matched.

```
findFile("/home", "abc.json")
findFile("/home", "prefix-*.json")
```

**Update**

I got it working with below code -

```
func findFile(root string, fileName string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.WalkDir(root, func(pathh string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if !d.IsDir() {
            if ok, err := path.Match(fileName, d.Name()); ok && err == nil {
                files = append(files, pathh)
            }
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}
```

Let me know if it looks good. Also anything I can simplify in my above code as I got two separate if conditions one by one. Can they be combined in one if condition?

Comment: You have a couple options. You could use a glob library like [go-glob](https://github.com/ryanuber/go-glob). Or you could check if the file name includes an asterisk, and if it does, create a regexp pattern with the asterisk replaced by `.*` to match anything. Then test the file names against the pattern.

Comment: `if strings.Contains(fileName, "*") { regex = regexp.MustCompile(strings.ReplaceAll(fileName, "*", ".*")) }` for example

Comment: What will you recommend then? I will be running this quite often and want to make sure it is efficient. @Jesse

Comment: Can you provide an example with `go-glob` basis on my example if possible so that I can understand better? @Jesse

Comment: I take back what I said, `path.Match()` will do all of this for you. `d.Name() == fileName` turns into `path.Match(fileName, d.Name())` https://pkg.go.dev/path#Match

Comment: I already tried running my code as it is on my second use case but it doesn't print anything at all. First use case works fine but second one doesn't work if I try with `findFile("/home", "prefix-*.json")`. Any idea what could be wrong? @Jesse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as I got two separate if conditions one by one. Can they be combined in one if condition?

No: keeping those conditions separate is clearer.

And since [`ryanuber/go-glob`](https://github.com/ryanuber/go-glob) is meant to compare two arbitrary strings, [`path.Match(fileName, d.Name())`](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Match) is enough in your case, since you are comparing paths.